# Texture pack not showing up in Minecraft client

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been trying to use a texture pack. I made one and just tried to change 1 painting and the damage sounds. I'm pretty sure everything is formatted correctly and the image files are the right sizes. I'm not sure how I'd show the files on the forum, but this is how my `.mcmeta` file is formatted:

```
{
  "pack": {
    "pack_format": 6,
    "description": "The Stinkiest Pack Around"
  }
}
```

It doesn't load into the resource pack menu, even when the file is compressed into a zip and placed in the `.minecraft/resourcepacks` folder.

Edit: Just realized that the `.mcmeta` formatting goes weird on the forum post. Everything is spaced normally, and not how it appears on this post.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Posts on our network are formatted using Markdown. Place three backticks around your code and it will become a preformatted text block.

Comment: Please also note that our rules and practices are quite different from other forum boards, so much that we have agreed on the fact: **Arqade is not a forum.** Please be sure to read our [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) to make sure you don't make the same mistakes as other new users.

Comment: Can you please post your folder structure? Try consulting [this](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Creating_a_resource_pack) first.

Comment: Is it zipped or unzipped? It should be unzipped

Answer (score 1):

Your .mcmeta file looks correct, this is how the file structure should look like inside of the Minecraft resourcepacks folder:

```
\"Your Resource pack"\
> assets
> pack.mcmeta
> pack.png

\"Your Resource pack"\assets\minecraft\
> blockstates
> font
> lang
> models
> particles
> shaders
> sounds
> texts
> textures

\"Your Resource pack"\assets\minecraft\textures\
> block
> colormap
> effect
> entity
> environment
> font
> gui
> item
> map
> misc
> mob_effect
> models
> painting
> particle
```

And make sure the "Your Resource pack" folder is a normal folder and not an archive such as .zip.

Because you only changed 2 things your folder could look like this:

```
\"Your Resource pack"\
> assets
> pack.mcmeta
> pach.png

\"Your Resource pack"\assets\minecraft\
> sounds
> textures

\"Your Resource pack"\assets\minecraft\textures\
> painting
```